# Can not choose porfolio category when add new page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I created some porfolio categories in my web, but I can not choose them from Template list when adding new page. Please see my images. 
[image]

[image]

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using attribute blog_term for assigning the porfolio category. Thanks

```
[tx_portfolio style="default" items="4" columns="4" hide_cat="no" hide_excerpt="no" show_pagination="no" carousel="no"  blog_term="thit"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are in the wrong place searching for categories. you added some portfolio categories on the portfolio section and you are looking for those categories on the pages section. the category should be assigned to some portfolio project and then displayed using a shortcode on the page. To find those go under Portfolio add new and you will see them on the right side.

Comment: Thanks ahmed, I did as this guide, but it doesn't display porfolio layouts at step 3.2 https://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-how-to-assign-a-portfolio-category-to-a-certain-portfolio-page.html